# Test Case: Leetcode Word Search

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I was working on Leetcode 79. Word Search today. The problem description is as follows:

"Given an m x n grid of characters board and a string word, return true if word exists in the grid.

The word can be constructed from letters of sequentially adjacent cells, where adjacent cells are horizontally or vertically neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once."

The current code solution I have is this:

```
def exist(self, board: List[List[str]], word: str) -> bool:
        row = len(board)
        col = len(board[0])
        q = collections.deque()
        visited = set()
        wordArray = []
        
        def bfs(row, col, word):
            for ch in word:
                wordArray.append(ch)
            directions = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]
            for r in range(row):
                for c in range(col):
                    q.append((r, c))
            while q:
                r, c = q.popleft()
                if (r, c) not in visited and board[r][c] in wordArray:
                    wordArray.remove(board[r][c])
                visited.add((r, c))
                for dr, dc in directions:
                    newR = r + dr
                    newC = c + dc
                    if newR in range(row) and newC in range(col):
                        if (newR, newC) not in visited and board[newR][newC] in wordArray:
                            visited.add((newR, newC))
                            wordArray.remove(board[newR][newC])
                            q.append((newR, newC))
                        
        bfs(row, col, word)
        if len(wordArray) == 0:
            return True
        return False
```

However, it appears that this code fails for the test case [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]. I'm a little confused on why this is. Going by my code logic, I believe that the square containing d would get popped first, then d would be removed in wordArray. I would then traverse to b and c, which should by similar logic also be added to visited and removed from wordArray. Then, I would eventually arrive at a, which should not yet be visited and thus, would cause a to be removed from ["abcd"]. Thus, all four letters would be gone. The neighbors of "a" would then be checked but since they've all been visited, nothing should happen, and it should return to the normal function, with len(wordArray) now being 0, causing the function to return True. Where did I go wrong in my tracing? I thought everything was correct logically.

Comment: You DO return True.  That's the problem.  That answer is wrong. because 'b' and 'c' are not adjacent.  You have to go in order.  You start with "a".  From "a" you can move to "b".  But from "b", you cannot get to "c" -- the only remaining neighbor is "d".

Comment: You are going to find that a BFS is the wrong approach.  They have some pathological cases that will kill you.  A DFS does a better job.